# Are [causality] and [causal-inference] tags the same?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags [causality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causality) and [causal-inference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causal-inference) that seem identical or at least closely related -- aren't they? Reviewing the posts tagged by both tags shows that there is not much difference between them. Maybe they should be merged?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I read your question I first wanted to comment pointing out a possible difference in meaning between these two tags.

But then I looked at what questions are tagged with each of them, and I actually see no difference at all. **It's a mess!** Given this random usage, I agree that the tags should better be merged.

[causality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causality) (35) $\leftarrow$ [causal-inference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/causal-inference) (225)

Even though the second tag has many more threads, most of them are actually about "causality" in general and not about some specific inference procedures. I have written a brief wiki excerpt for `[causality]`, so the merge is ready to go.

Comment: With +5 votes, no comments and no objections we probably could close this thread and agree with amoeba?

Comment: @Tim, tag synonyms are sometimes a bit hard to push through. I suggest we wait for 1 week (as opposed to 1 day) and then, if it's still not done, ping one of the moderators in chat, e.g. Scortchi (who helped to implement several recent tag merges). Maybe you can try not to forget about it :-)

Comment: @Tim, as I said before, I don't think that accepting an answer with a specific suggestion on meta is helpful before this suggestion is implemented. Now for somebody looking through the list of questions on meta main page this thread will appear as "resolved" (green), but it is actually not resolved in the sense that it requires moderator action. So I would suggest to leave it un-accepted for now. Experience tells me that moderators usually do implement the tag merges, but it can take a long time. If you are impatient, it might help to politely ping one of them.

Comment: so it seems I do not fully understand the accept button in meta. As for me the thread is closed.

Comment: I've merged them now.

Comment: @Tim: it's done, feel free to accept :-)